# access wcf service response in perl

Tags: wcf, perl

I have written a perl script to access a wcf service method which returns complex data. I am able to see the xml schema response from wcf service (using dumper in perl). but I am not able to access the values from the schema:

```
 $response1= $soap->GetAddress
(SOAP::Data->new(name=>'mailAddress',value=>[SOAP::Data->new (name=>'a:city'),
SOAP::Data->new (name=>'a:name'),SOAP::Data->new (name=>'a:streetaddress'),SOAP::Data->new 
(name=>'a:zipcode')])->attr({'xmlns:a'=>$xmlns}))->result;
```

I am using this to access the methods from the service. How can I read the values from `$response1`?

$response1:

```
 $VAR1 = {
      'city' => 'Hyd',
      'streetaddress' => 'ECIL',
      'name' => 'Avinash Patil',
      'zipcode' => '5000012',
      'state' => 'AP'
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response1=$soap->getCustomer(SOAP::Data->new(name => 'customerid', value =>$custid))->result;
print $response1->{'Email'};
print "\n";
print $response1->{'Mobile'};
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
my @values;

my $value[0]= $soap->'Method-name'($header,$data)->valueof('//city');
my $value[1]= $soap->'Method-name'($header,$data)->valueof('//streetaddress');
my $value[2]= $soap->'Method-name'($header,$data)->valueof('//name');
my $value[3]= $soap->'Method-name'($header,$data)->valueof('//state');
```